# vertical View Pager animation in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am very new to android ,i trying to implement vertical view pager with zoom out page transformer my vertical view pager working fine when i come for zoomout page transformer   it will scroll horizontally ,it was not scrolling vertically

my vertical view pager class
**VerticalViewPager.class**

```
public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {
public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    // The majority of the magic happens here
    setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
    // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
    setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}

private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
            view.setAlpha(1);

            // Counteract the default slide transition
            view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

            //set Y position to swipe in from top
            float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
            view.setTranslationY(yPosition);

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
 */
private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
    float width = getWidth();
    float height = getHeight();

    float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
    float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

    ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

    return ev;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
    return intercepted;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
}

}
```

my zoomout animation class 
**AnimationViewPager.class**

```
public class AnimationViewPager implements VerticalViewPager.PageTransformer {

private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;

public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

    if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
        // This page is way off-screen to the left.
        view.setAlpha(0);

    } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
        // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page

        view.setAlpha(1);
        view.setTranslationX(0);
        view.setScaleX(1);
        view.setScaleY(1);

    } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
        // Fade the page out.
        view.setAlpha(1 - position);

        // Counteract the default slide transition
        view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);
        // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
        float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
        view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
        view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

    } else { // (1,+Infinity]
        // This page is way off-screen to the right.
        view.setAlpha(0);
    }
}


}
```

here my sample image i am trying to like this,please any one help me how to get this

[image]

Comment: This might help : https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager

Answer (score 3):

firstly use this lib. it's the most closet to the out of box one ,
link given below
 github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager

then create a new class

```
public class DepthPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;

public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

    if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
        // This page is way off-screen to the left.
        view.setAlpha(0);

    } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
        // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
        view.setAlpha(1);
        view.setTranslationX(0);
        view.setScaleX(1);
        view.setScaleY(1);

    } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
        // Fade the page out.
        view.setAlpha(1 - position);

        // Counteract the default slide transition
        view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

        // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
        float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
        view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
        view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

    } else { // (1,+Infinity]
        // This page is way off-screen to the right.
        view.setAlpha(0);
    }
}
}
```

in your mainactivity class, set the animation on verticalviewpager class like this

```
     verticalViewPager=(VerticalViewPager)findViewById(R.id.verticalview);

     verticalViewPager.setPageTransformer(false,new DepthPageTransformer());
     verticalViewPager.setAdapter(pager);
```

that's it, thank you and please rate my answer :)